# Laravel returning to same page if popup clicked

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.4

I have three functionalities to be done only after logging in. Once they click the  button, it checks for login. if not logged in, it show the popup and make them to login.

Am using that login popup for initial login. Same controller function and returning back.

Now my problem is, I had add leads popup. when they click add leads, it show login popup. After logging in, I have to show the same leads popup. But that should not affect other log in. This has to be implemented in four other functionalities.

how to find where the log in is done and return back accordingly?

Controller Code:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this -> validate($request,[
        'useremail' =>'required',
    ]);

    $res = StandardUser::where('useremail', Input::get('useremail'))->first();
    $email = $request->useremail;

    if ($res) {
        $userid = json_decode($res)->id;
        $firstname = json_decode($res)->firstname;
        $lastname = json_decode($res)->lastname;
        $managerfirstname = json_decode($res)->manager_firstname;
        $managerlastname = json_decode($res)->manager_lastname;
        $manageremail = json_decode($res)->manager_email;

        return back()
            ->withCookie(cookie('uemail', $email))
            ->cookie('uid', $userid)
            ->cookie('ufn', $firstname)
            ->cookie('uln', $lastname)
            ->cookie('mfn', $managerfirstname)
            ->cookie('mln', $managerlastname)
            ->cookie('memail', $manageremail);
    }else{
        $standarduser = StandardUser::create($request->all());
        $userid = $standarduser->id;

        return back()
            ->withCookie(cookie('uemail', $email))
            ->cookie('uid', $userid);       
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, inside your `ajax()` login function pass a `callback` kind of parameter that contains the name of the function that is to be executes when login is successful.

By using this callback function you can decide whether it requires redirection or reload or to call a function that initiate some other popup kind of thing.

Comment: Can't get you clearly. Am not using ajax. Just a controller function. I think you are saying after controller function, login successful, add a function that tells to return where? Right?

Answer (score 0):

To do this with minor changes, 
take a hidden field in you login for popup and print the redirect url here with a query string parameter named as `'ajax'` like `"/controller/action?data='ajax'"`.
Then in your login controller where you did the redirection, check the post data of the hidden field that if in the query string, data has the parameter `'ajax'` then redirect to this hidden field url other wise redirect to other one which you want.

Comment: Great idea. I will check it and convey you

Comment: Sure Kayal, Revert me in case of any issue

Comment: How to redirect along with popup opening? It returns in the redirection itself

Comment: added in my question